# Appcelerator: Pagination for Views in IPhone

Tags: iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I want to show  remotely fetched records and want to display in same format as Apple shows Icons on Home Screen. I also want pagination ( the dots on bottom) for indication of currently selected page. How could it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [ScrollableView](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-object) component. Use the [HTTPClient](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object.html) to retrieve your data from the server, create views/imageviews/etc from the data as appropriate, then add the views as children to the ScrollableView.